# View Pager 2 swipe between tabs doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I'm facing some problem with my `ViewPager2`. I have used a standard `viewpager` but since the `FragmentPagerAdapter` is deprecated I decided to migrate to ViewPager2.

That's how it looks like now

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fragment : Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment)  {


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 3
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when(position){
        0 -> Fragment1()
        1 -> Fragment2()
        2 -> Fragment3()
        else -> Fragment1()
    }
}


class RozliczanieFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    _binding = FragBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    val viewPager = binding.pager
    val pagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this)
    viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    val tabs = binding.tab
    TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager){
            tab, position ->
        when(position){
            0 -> tab.text = "1"
            1 -> tab.text = "2"
            2 -> tab.text = "3"
        }
    }.attach()

    return binding.root
}
```

My `ViewPager2` is inside another fragment so i used `FragmentStateAdapter` and passed fragment as arg.

The problem is **I can't change tab/fragment using swipe**. With standard `ViewPager` everything was fine. What can be a problem? I couldn't find much information about the implementation of `ViewPager2` inside of another fragment, so maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: It depends on what your viewpager2 is contained in. `ViewPager` does page scroll by intercepting touch event, `ViewPager2` embeds a RecyclerView which can be affected by nested scrolling.

Comment: Can you add this line `viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = true ` after assigning `viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter`. I assume view pager swipe is disabled by default for `ViewPager2`  and making it true manually should resolve it.

Comment: @AnirudhGoud that didn't work for me. Simon, did you find a fix ?